# Filter out hidden folder using client object model in sharepoint 2013

Tags: client-object-model, provider-hosted-app

I am adding list and library in treeview but it also displaying the "Forms", "Attachements", "Item" hidden folder in treeview.

Any one has any idea to hide that folder using client object model?

I'm using below code:

```
public static List<FolderInfo> GetFoldersInFolder(Folder folder, Web web, ClientContext clientContext) {
    List<FolderInfo> result = new List<FolderInfo>();
    FolderInfo folderinfo;
    FolderCollection subFolders = folder.Folders;clientContext.Load(folder);
    clientContext.Load<FolderCollection>(s‌​ubFolders);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (Folder subFolder in subFolders){
        folderinfo = new FolderInfo();
        folderinfo.Name = subFolder.Name;
        folderinfo.URL = subFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        result.Add(folderinfo);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you created for this?

Comment: Using below code I'm adding each folder:

Comment: public static List<FolderInfo> GetFoldersInFolder(Folder folder, Web web, ClientContext clientContext)
        {List<FolderInfo> result = new List<FolderInfo>();FolderInfo folderinfo;FolderCollection subFolders = folder.Folders;clientContext.Load(folder);clientContext.Load<FolderCollection>(subFolders);clientContext.ExecuteQuery();foreach (Folder subFolder in subFolders){folderinfo = new FolderInfo();folderinfo.Name = subFolder.Name;folderinfo.URL = subFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;result.Add(folderinfo);}return result;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to exclude "system" folders using SharePoint CSOM

[Folder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder(v=office.15).aspx) exposes [Folder.ListItemAllFields property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.listitemallfields(v=office.15).aspx) that specifies the list item associated with the folder, for "system" folders the corresponding list item does not exist.

The following example demonstrates how to verify whether the folder is regular or "system" folder:

```
bool regularFolder = subFolder.ListItemAllFields.ServerObjectIsNull != null && !subFolder.ListItemAllFields.ServerObjectIsNull.Value;
```

**Fixed example**

```
public static List<FolderInfo> GetFoldersInFolder(Folder folder, Web web)
{
    var ctx = web.Context as ClientContext;
    var result = new List<FolderInfo>();
    ctx.Load(folder.Folders, fcol => fcol.Include(f => f.Name, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl, f => f.ListItemAllFields));
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var subFolder in folder.Folders)
    {
            if (subFolder.ListItemAllFields.ServerObjectIsNull != null && !subFolder.ListItemAllFields.ServerObjectIsNull.Value)
            {
                var folderinfo = new FolderInfo {Name = subFolder.Name, URL = subFolder.ServerRelativeUrl};
                result.Add(folderinfo);    
            }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Using this code:

Comment: bool regularFolder = subFolder.ListItemAllFields.ServerObjectIsNull != null && !subFolder.ListItemAllFields.ServerObjectIsNull.Value;

Comment: I am also getting null value for created folder or other than hidden folder like "Media Player" in "Style Library" . so your code is not working. Anything else I need to check.

Comment: Have you tried the fixed example i've provided?

Comment: It will return only user-defined folders, i've tested it

Comment: ok, let me try with your code.

Comment: Most probably the reason why you are getting NULL values  for subFolder.ListItemAllFields.ServerObjectIsNull since you forgot to explicitly load it like in my example: f => f.ListItemAllFields

Comment: yes, your code is working fine. thanks for your help.

Comment: Vadim, ctx.ExecuteQuery(); taking long time to execute. Do you have any idea about that ? Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: @VadimGremyachev It does not work in SharePoint 2010 since the property `ListItemAllFields` not available. Is there any work around to get regular folders in 
SharePoint 2010 ?