# Filter out hidden folder using client object model in SharePoint 2010 / 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, caml-query, csom, folder

I need to do the same thing as on this thread:
[Filter out hidden folder using client object model in sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126681/filter-out-hidden-folder-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2013)

However my code needs to run on SharePoint 2010 and Sharepoint 2013.
I'm using the CSOM API 2013 and calling the method:
`subFolder.ListItemAllFields`

which throws the "Method or property ListItemAllFields does not exist" on SharePoint 2010.
Does anyone know any workaround for this issue?
I know that the method is not exposed in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it.
Answer is the combination of CSOM and CAML query.
CAML query returns only user visible folder's without any tweaking which is exactly what I need.
This approach works on SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013

Here's the code sample that recursively searches trough the SharePoint list and fills the TreeView:

```
    public TreeViewItem getRootTree(string libraryTitle) {
        Folder rootFolder = getRootFolder(libraryTitle);
        TreeViewItem rootItem = new TreeViewItem();

        rootItem.Header = rootFolder.Name;
        rootItem.Tag = rootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        rootItem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        addTreeChildren(rootFolder, rootItem);

        return rootItem;
    }

    private void addTreeChildren(Folder parentFolder, TreeViewItem parentNode) {
        CamlQuery spQuery = new CamlQuery();
        String xmlCamlQuery = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
        spQuery.ViewXml = xmlCamlQuery;
        spQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = parentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;

        ListItemCollection items = currentLibrary.GetItems(spQuery);
        spClientContext.Load(items);
        spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (ListItem item in items) {
            Folder folder = getListItemFolder(item);
            TreeViewItem childItem = new TreeViewItem();
            childItem.Header = folder.Name;
            childItem.Tag = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
            childItem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            parentNode.Items.Add(childItem);

            addTreeChildren(folder, childItem);
        }
    }

    private Folder getListItemFolder(ListItem listItem) {
        spClientContext.Load(listItem, li => li.ParentList.ParentWeb);
        spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        Folder parentFolder = listItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl((string)listItem["FileRef"]);
        listItem.Context.Load(parentFolder);
        listItem.Context.ExecuteQuery();
        return parentFolder;
    }
```

This CAML query returns all first level folders:
`String xmlCamlQuery = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";`

This CAML query returns all subfolders (recursive search):
`String xmlCamlQuery = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";`

I use my own recursion to fill the library folder tree and ListItem is converted to Folder object like this:
`Folder parentFolder = listItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl((string)listItem["FileRef"]);`
`"FileRef"` field is folder's server relative URL.